# QGIS 3.10.1: add photos to attribute table using only relative path

Tags: qgis

I want to create a shapefile from geotagged photos using only relative path (to display photos from any other GIS software alongside other informations in the shp).

I imported photos using Import Photo plugin and exported them to shp, but when i open the shp from another machine, photos don't show up and an error message appears "No image Path found"

Is there a solution to make it work?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Are the paths exactly the same on both machines?

Comment: that's what i want to achieve ! a standard path that can allow photos to be displayed in any machine.

Comment: That wont work if you store them on C:/ unless you make it a shared resource you can access from all machines.

Comment: how can i do that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering the developer website (https://mariosmsk.com/2019/07/02/qgis-plugin-importphotos/) and tutorial video available there, you should add 2 fields: `Path` and `RelPath`.
And `RelPath` should rely on './' schema of up/down folders.